# Как сделать, чтобы форма открывалась в окне при запуске, а не на весь экран в Access?

Tags: access, ms-access

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы форма открывалась в окне при запуске, а не на весь экран (в правой стороне) в Access?

Comment: Auto Resize = No

Comment: и , если у вас не popup, то почитайте тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/access.form.popup